# Is it normal for an experienced Finish Carpenter to put so many blemishes on walls during a kitchen cabinet install?

Tags: kitchens, cabinets, carpentry, finish

[image]I recently hired a Finish Carpenter with “30+ years of experience” to install my white finish, plywood cabinets.  I paid $1400 for him to mount 10 boxes (he only mounted 9 but still charged $1400 plus tax).  It took him at most 14 hours over 2 days.

**Question:**  What level of workmanship should I expect?  For instance, you have a professionals, amateurs, and DIYers.  Based on the picture (I can only upload one) was his work typical of a professional?

He put a lot of blemishes (pencil marks, dents/dings with a hammer and nail gun, holes with a drill) on walls that I just primed/textured/spray painted.  His method of finding the stud was to estimate where it was and then drill until he found it.  He usually found the stud after about 6 tries.

He left a 1/4” gap between the wall and crown molding.  He used off-white spackle to cover nail holes.

He also didn’t properly secure a refrigerator panel (it’s loose), installed kick plate even though floors still have to be installed, and left all the trash piled up in an empty bedroom.

When I questioned his workmanship I got the “30+ years of experience” line and the logic that his worst blemishes would be hidden (a lot won’t be hidden).  I asked him if he used his stud finding method to hang a picture in his house.  He didn’t answer.

I’m just learning how to paint.  I don’t have any experience caulking joints and touching up.  Touching up the crown molding is going to be difficult for me.  I’m going to mask off a huge area and then spray.

**Question:** Once again, was his work typical of a professional?

Comment: Did you get any references before employing this trader? It is common to find out who people employ in the area...

Comment: You should never complete the final wall finish prior to cabinet installation. I'm not saying the work was perfect because we can't see that in a single pic, but installing cabinets is going to cause some bumps and scrapes...

Comment: While I'm not impressed with his stud-finding method (electronic stud finders are reasonably cheap & effective these days), I can't argue with his point that the holes & marks will be hidden as soon as you fit a counter-top (even without any back-splash). I've seen worse behind cabinets I've removed in the past.

Comment: I agree with @brhans he was trying to find something solid but that won’t matter later I would be concerned that he is not pre drilling and splitting the framework. 10 boxes should be 1 day unless the boxes had to be brought in from the next county over.

Comment: Tax on his labor? What location is this?